# Как выводить аватарку в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Как выводить аву в Wordpress?

[image]

```
<div class="login_form_widget">
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo '
        <script src="http://loginza.ru/js/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <a href="http://loginza.ru/api/widget?token_url=http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" class="loginza">
                <img src="http://loginza.ru/img/sign_in_button_gray.gif" alt="Войти через loginza"/>
            </a>
        ';
    wp_login_form(); ?>
    <p>
        <?php if ( get_option( 'users_can_register' ) ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=register', 'login' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Register' ); ?></a> | <?php endif; ?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Забыли пароль?</a>
    </p><?php } 
       else { ?>
          <?php global $user_identity;
              get_currentuserinfo(); ?>
        <div id="ava"><?php echo get_avatar($id_or_email, 62); ?></div>
          <p id="login"><strong><?php echo $user_identity; ?></strong></p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php">Изменить профиль</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">Выйти</a></li>
            </ul>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то:

```
function get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size = '96', $default = '', $alt = false ) {
```

Функция принимает `id` пользователя или его емейл.

Comment: да че то никак...в верхней панели показывается норм, а тут никак...и из соц сетей (плагин логинза) тоже нормально показывает...

Comment: Входные данные проверьте, что в качестве первого аргумента передается ?

Comment: Сейчас выложу весь код...